# Is it possible to disable System.Console XOFF/XON flow control processing in my C# app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, remote-desktop, windows-console

I am a developer of console-based server software, that occasionally seems to lock up on input until Enter is pressed. I suspect this is XOFF/XON (Ctrl-S/Ctrl-Q flow control) handling in System.Console windows.

Is it possible (using .NET calls or Win32 API functions) to disable XOFF/XON flow control processing in my C#/.NET application that uses System.Console for output and input commands?  (This also affects other system consoles such as CMD.EXE windows, but I don't care about those cases.) My app is server software; don't ever want a key that freezes the console, especially one that can be triggered accidentally as this appears to be.

Somehow I believe my server app's console is getting a Ctrl-S on input, or perhaps the Ctrl qualifier is thought to be pressed when S is entered. Console locks up until I hit Enter. (I'm thinking Ctrl-Q would have also released it but haven't had another opportunity to test that yet.)

My processes are C# servers on .NET, and these are consoles using System.Console.ReadLine() on Hyper-V VMs running Windows Server.

This may be critical to the problem cause: I am connecting to the Hyper-V host via Remote Desktop (RDP). One thought is the RDP disconnect is losing a Ctrl key up and then the next 'S' that is input (by our command automation software) locks the terminal.  We are eventually replacing that with network-based command input, but in the meantime we are fighting with this problem, which requires manual intervention by staff to get the server running again.

Further info: I tried the following, in case it was Quick Edit mode being triggered by an RDP session from a tablet, but this did not stop the lockups:

```
        GetConsoleMode(handle, out oldmode);

        int newmode = oldmode;
        newmode |= ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS;   // required to disable the next two
        newmode &= ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE; // force this OFF
        newmode &= ~ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT;     // force this OFF
        newmode &= ~ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT;    // force this OFF
        newmode |= ENABLE_INSERT_MODE;      // force this ON
        if (newmode != oldmode)
        {
            SetConsoleMode(handle, newmode);
```

Comment: I am new to posting on Stack Overflow, but maybe somebody can explain why someone would down-vote this question. It seems ideal for Stack Overflow, as it is a question of coding software to interact with the operating system, with a significant problem for server software that uses System.Console (or system consoles), that does not seem to be covered on Stack Overflow or anywhere on Google. (I looked for hours before posting.)  I am asking: does anybody know of a Win32 API that accomplishes this operation?

Comment: On Linux consoles, this can be accomplished with: "stty -ixon". There doesn't seem to be a Windows API equivalent except for actual serial ports.  It seems to be hard-coded to always be enabled under Windows, which is a very nasty situation for servers or real-time apps.

Comment: The only answers I have found is to just _not_ _use_ System.Console here but to open my own window and reimplement the same functionality that I am using in System.Console (or find someone who has already reimplemented it), _without_ flow control.  Alternatively, perhaps queuing the calls to System.Console.WriteLine and System.Console.ReadLine from a separate thread would answer this. (That would create it's own problems though, with a queue backlog.)

Comment: You should fix the title to make it clear you are trying to change the behavior of your own application, which uses the CONSOLE subsystem.  Right now it sounds like you are trying to affect built-in programs.

Comment: Ah good point, thank you. Done.

Comment: There seems to be *nothing at all* about this in MSDN, StackOverflow or even a Google search, so I recognize that I'm probably asking "the wrong question". Maybe I don't need to disable XON/XOFF flow control; I just don't want WriteLine to block up on output to a normal console window, just because someone pressed Ctrl-S or something. I'm unsure how this is even happening, other than that several of our consoles lock up with this problem each week, until staff connects and hits Enter. If anyone has any out-of-box alternatives other than rewrite my own console class, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Yes it is very surprising.  I was mostly convinced you were crazy and that this was a shell function, not part of CSRSS.exe (console subsystem), until I tried it myself.  Wanting to disable or intercept these is a very reasonable thing.  I presume you've tested to see whether you get a console-control-handler callback (with undocumented cause) when these combinations are used?  And that you've tried the other console mode flags as well?

Comment: In any case, a queue backlog wouldn't be a problem, it's exactly what you desire (unless you want output to just be dropped while the terminal is paused in XOFF state -- but a ring buffer with a maximum size is easily implemented too)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is safe to conclude after all these years without a solution or anything to contradict or workaround the issue, that disabling flow control on a standard C# console app on Windows is is not possible, and that this leaves console apps that accept input (such as Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Break) open to hangs caused by XOFF characters. This means it is not suitable for most servers.